# AngularJS - ng-model not updating correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have this piece of HTML:

```
:
:
<td ng-if="Curr_State == 'Edit' && This_Page.Data_Changed == false" style="max-width:300px">
    <button type="button"
            class="FD" 
            ng-click="Initiate_Append_to_JobCard()" 
            style="height:80px;width:180px;white-space:normal;background:green;padding:10px">
        <font size="3" class="ng-binding">Append{{All_Labels.Common.Append}}
        </font>
        <font size="2">
            {{This_Page.Append_Get_Number}}
            <table id="Get_Append_Count_an_Execute" ng-if="This_Page.Append_Get_Number == 'Y'">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="Append_Number"> #:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input string-to-number
                                   id="Append_Number"
                                   type="number" 
                                   class="form-control" 
                                   ng-model="This_Page.Append_Number"
                                   min="0"
                                   step="1"
                                   style="width:70px;margin:0px">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" 
                                    ng-click="Do_Append()" 
                                    title="Proceed with Append"
                                    type="button">
                                <font size="2" color="white">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </font>
                         </button>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" 
                                    ng-click="Cancel_Append()" 
                                    title="Cancel Append request"
                                    type="button">
                                <font size="2" color="white">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </font>
                         </button>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </font>
    </button>
</td>
:
:
```

and the following two functions within the controller:

```
$scope.Initiate_Append_to_JobCard = function() {
    $scope.This_Page.Append_Get_Number = "Y" ;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$scope.Cancel_Append = function() {
    $scope.This_Page.Append_Get_Number = "N"   ;
    $scope.This_Page.Append_Number     = null  ;
}
```

When the outer button is clicked, `$scope.This_Page.Append_Get_Number` is set to `"Y"` and the inner objects are properly shown.

When the Cancel button is clicked, the function `$scope.Cancel_Append` is invoked, the value of `$scope.This_Page.Append_Get_Number` is set to `"N"` (first statement of the function) but this change is not propagated towards the HTML. In fact, I added `{{This_Page.Append_Get_Number}}` which shows initially `N`, then `Y` and it then remains unchanged no matter how many times I click on the cancel button.

Comment: You should use $scope.$apply()

Comment: This might be because of `ng-if` creating a new scope. Try `ng-model="$parent.This_Page.Append_Number"` or `ng-show`

Comment: Set `$scope.This_Page.Append_Number` to `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: @IrhadLjubcic, you cannot use the $apply() method while Angular is in the middle of a digest cycle, which is the case when you invoke a `$scope.xyz` function.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, switched to `ng-show` with no effect. The point is that switching from "N" to "Y" (function `$scope.Initiate_Append_to_JobCard`) works, but from "Y" to "N" (function $scope.Cancel_Append) does not. I set a breakpoint at the line that `$scope.This_Page.Append_Get_Number = "N"   ;`, it is executed, but its effect is not seen on the page.

Comment: @georgeawg, `$scope.This_Page.Append_Number` is just a number entered by the user within the input element. The issue is with the model variable that controls showing or not the inner table.

Comment: (you do have multiple `ng-if`s) Can you make a Plunker example?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I must **shamefully confess** that I have never done that, so need to learn how to do it.

Comment: Where is the closing `</button>` tag for the append button?

Comment: The closing button tag is at the bottom (after the table). That is the original problem. The closing button tag should be before the table

Comment: When posting code snippet, please spend some time to make it minimal and nice -- remove styles, classes, titles and rest irrelevant information.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, point taken. Thanks.

Comment: @georgeawg, the layout is correct (or, that was the intention): There is a button labeled "Append" that, when clicked, three elements are supposed to appear **WITHIN** that very same button: and input element and two additional buttons, OK and Cancel. When either OK or Cancel are clicked, these three first should disappear. I have in many places elements (tables included) that are shown/ hidden using `ng-if` and everywhere it works perfectly, but not here....

Comment: @PrabhuThomas, see my response to georgeawg.

Comment: @FDavidov, Have updated my answer and also the plunker. Its working with the table inside the button

Comment: @georgeawg, you marked the question as duplicate, right... I changed the outer button to a clickable div and it is still not working. Moreover, the inner button with `ng-click="Do_Append()"` works perfectly in the sense that it invokes the function (Do_Append) and yields the desired result. So, buttons within buttons DO WORK (at least in my case), but AngularJS binding appears NOT TO WORK. Do you still consider it a duplicate?

Comment: @georgeawg, check Thomas solution. I works perfectly as expected. So much for **duplicate**... :-(.

Comment: **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.**  [Validate](https://validator.w3.org/) any HTML or XML.

Comment: @georgeawg, thanks for the link. Quite interesting and I guess helpful. Unfortunately (at least for the current case), the application is not and will never be accessible from the public network (security reasons). The interesting thing is that the addition of the `event` thing (see Thomas' answer) did solve the problem, though I don't quite understand why (asked Thomas for a brief explanation).

Comment: @FDavidov, have added an explanation in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="button"
            class="FD" 
            ng-click="Initiate_Append_to_JobCard()" 
            style="height:80px;width:180px;white-space:normal;background:green;padding:10px">
        <font size="3" class="ng-binding">Append{{All_Labels.Common.Append}}
        </font>
        <font size="2">
            {{This_Page.Append_Get_Number}} </font></button>

<table id="Get_Append_Count_an_Execute" ng-if="This_Page.Append_Get_Number == 'Y'">
```

If the table should be inside the button itself, then the click event on the Cancel button will bubble up to the Append button, which will close and open again.

You need to add a

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

in your cancel function and also pass the **$event** to that function

### Updated Plunker

https://embed.plnkr.co/CEHNggASaVGqkqfamdEx/

### Event Bubbling

When you have an element inside another element and an event occurs on the innermost element (the click event here), then the event is processed by that element and then it is passed up the DOM hierarchy to all the ancestor elements that have a listener for that event and processed by each one.

Here you have a button inside a button, with click event listeners on both. When the inner button (Cancel) is clicked, the listener (Cancel_Append) processes the event (changes the value to N) and then passes the click to the parent/outer button where the listener (Initiate_Append_to_JobCard) processes the event and changes the value to Y again.

Since these happen at almost the same time, we cant see the difference. It can be seen by adding a 'console.log($scope.This_Page.Append_Get_Number)' to both the functions.

To prevent the bubbling of the event, we need to cancel the propagation after the event has been handled. So we need to pass the **$event** object from the HTML and then after the event is processed by the "Cancel_Append", we need to stop propagating the event further up the DOM using the event.stopPropagation().

Take a look at this link for a better understanding of event bubbling

[What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Hey Thomas, I checked the plunker you posted and, for some reason, it does not finish its loading (and hence cannot see how it works). Anyway, I didn't quite see any difference between your posted solution and my code (except for the `event.stopPropagation()` that does not make any difference).

Comment: @FDavidov, did you add the $event when you are calling the cancel function in the HTML ---> ng-click="Cancel_Append($event)"  https://run.plnkr.co/W5LgWMF7IsWEsN2e/

Comment: Yeap. Same result (not hiding the table).

Comment: Funny, it works fine for me

Comment: I saw the new link and indeed works!!!

Comment: Did you change anything from my code?

Comment: I added only the $event in the HTML and the event.stopPropagation()

Comment: BINGO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It works!!!!! I misunderstood your wording regarding the event. Checked you example, reproduced what you did and EUREKA!!!! Thank you Sir!!!!!!!!!!! (needless to say, you get my vote).

Comment: Thomas, I thought about your solution and would like to ask you for a brief explanation on why the addition of the **event** solved the problem, could you kindly post it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thomas, description is crystal clear. I am aware about bubbling but didn't think in that direction. Many thanks for the answer and your time Sir!!!

Answer (score 0):

make use of ng-show instead of ng-if

```
<td ng-show="Curr_State == 'Edit' && This_Page.Data_Changed == false" style="max-width:300px">
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem I posted.

Comment: it will work fine, if you use ng-show instead of ng-if since when using ng-if the DOM element is rendered later.

Comment: It works fine using ng-if also. The problem was with the table being inside the button tag itself. Have added a plunker to my answer